# What is the state-of-the-art in prediction\classification missing labels in partially labeled data?

Tags: python, time-series, predictive-modeling, missing-data, semi-supervised-learning

### Overview

Let's say I have the following data:

```py
#                       Label\Target    VM
#2000-01-01 00:00:00        App3        VM9
#2000-01-01 01:00:00        App3        VM3
#2000-01-01 02:00:00        App1        VM1
#2000-01-01 03:00:00        App1        VM8
#2000-01-01 04:00:00    ->  None        VM1
#...                        ...         ...
#2000-12-31 19:00:00    ->  None        VM5
#2000-12-31 20:00:00        App3        VM1
#2000-12-31 21:00:00        App3        VM7
#2000-12-31 22:00:00        App1        VM3
#2000-12-31 23:00:00        App2        VM8
```

I have 3 classes `(App1, App2, App3)` + `None`.

> `None` represents missing values in `Label\Target` column.

---

## Problem definition

**Problem:** is to classify\predict **missing** values represented by `None`  in `Label\Target` column given a time series.

> `None ==?==> (App1, App2, App3)?`

I'm unsure which approach to take with **partially** labeled data.

- Approach1: consider 3 classes `(App1, App2, App3)`
- Approach2: consider 4 classes `(App1, App2, App3)` + `None`

**Which method should I use?**

The thing that crossed my mind is [Self-Supervised Learning](https://amitness.com/2020/02/illustrated-self-supervised-learning/) (SSL)

[image: img]

What about **Self-Supervised Learning**?

I did some research to see the best practice to approach this problem and what is State-of-the-art. I found this [article](https://www.vanderschaar-lab.com/self-semi-supervised-learning/):

[image: img]

How about **Semi-Supervised Learning**?

> *"Semi-supervised learning is particularly useful when there is a large amount of unlabeled data available, but it’s too expensive or difficult to label all of it."* [Ref](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-semi-supervised-learning/)

[image: img]

But still, I'm confused and even unsure if this problem is *classify\predict* or *forecast* missing label.

### Reproducible data generation

Following is sampled data if you had a Pythonic solution:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
np.random.seed(2023)

# Generate TS

ts = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2000-12-31 23:00', freq='H') 
# number of samples
N = len(ts)

# Create a random dataset
data = {
    #"TS": ts,
    'Appx':  [random.choice(['App1', 'App2', 'App3', None])                for _ in range(N)],
    'VM':    [random.choice(['VM1' , 'VM2' , 'VM3', 'VM4', 'VM5', 'VM6'])  for _ in range(N)]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=ts)
df
```

---

## Question

I need best practice to frame the problem correctly for this scenario to predict missing labels in partially labeled data over time and possible approaches (Approach1 or 2) based on state-of-the-art and recent methods (Semi\Self-supervised learning). I have generated sample data if someone wants to offer the minimal solution(s).

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would frame this problem as a **denoising** task, that is, having a model learn to reconstruct a corrupted input. In this case, the noise to remove would be the missing label/target's. For this, you would need enough fully labeled data to train the model, which would be artificially corrupted by replacing the label/target with some special `[MASK]` element. The model's expected output would be the correct label/target's at the masked positions.

Given that your data seems to be sequences of discrete elements, I would use a Transformer encoder, which can use the full sequence to make its predictions. Therefore, I would use something like [BERT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805).

The idea would be as follows (this assumes knowledge on BERT; please have a look at [this maked language modeling tutorial](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/masked_language_modeling) and the questions about BERT in this site for more):

- the model receives a sequence of pairs of symbols: [(label/target1, VM1), (label/target2, VM2), ...]. A percentage (e.g. 15%) of the input positions have their label/target replaced with a special `[MASK]` symbol.
- to feed the pair of symbols (label/target, VM) to the neural network, I would use separate embeddings for each component of the pair. At each position, we would embed each part of the pair and add together the resulting vectors, together with the Transformer's positional encodings.
- the model generates the (label/target) at each position. Only the positions where the input was masked are taken into account for the loss function.
- For the training data, you should have the sequences where you have all the label/target information.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Using your BERT-based approach means we have  3 classes `(App1, App2, App3)`, or we need to consider 4 classes `(App1, App2, App3)` + `None`?

Comment: You would need the normal label/target plus an option to mask. In my answer I referred to such an option as `[MASK]` to be consistent with BERT, but you can call it `None`.

Comment: Since we have a timestamp in data, is there any Time-series-based approach for our problem? Or do you think as long as we use sequenced-friendly Transfomer (i.e., BERT) according to [MASK] is good enough for this task, and we don't need to solve the problem we framed using time-series analytics? So, can we say that the state-of-the-art for this problem is a language model like BERT?

Comment: From your data, I understood that the intervals where regular (1h), so I assumed the ordering info would be enough. If this assumption is not acceptable, then I would add more info to each position depending on what is considered relevant by domain experts; for instance, if the hour is the relevant part, I would add a new  embedding to represent it (with 24 values, one for each hour of the day).

Comment: Of course, I am sure biased toward my own area of expertise, which is NLP, LMs, etc, and you know, to a hammer, everything looks like a nail  . There may be other timeseries-based approaches that are as valid or more valid than my proposal.

Comment: May I know if your proposed Approach using LM models like BERT using MASK has any alignment with [Skip-Gram](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/120337/69263) that counts as *Self-supervised* or not? In the comment under this [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/94956/69263), they addressed: *"The overall process of BERT, ELMo, etc. can be considered as 'Semi-supervised learning' because they including both LM(self-supervised) and supervised learning. The training process of LM is self-supervised learning."* Do you confirm it?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of both the skipgram model and BERT is to learn word/token representations.

Answer (score 0):

For tabular data simple boosted ml models are still a good choice, when compared to state of the art Fusion Transformers (2023), see https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.11959v3

Therefore, lalbel propagation like in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/semi_supervised.html still is a method worth trying.

If you deal with big clean data of a certain modality, then you might go with pretraining (like suggested by Noe with the masked language loss etc...) with unlabelled data and then adding a task head for whatever task you want so solve. Training the task head will still require you to have enough data.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Please feel free to extend your answer if you have minimal Pythonic implementation using `df` proposed at the end of my post.

Comment: Would you elaborate on how you frame the problem, i.e., *denoising*? What is the best approach to tackle this problem (e.g., SSL, LM models, etc.)? you proposed *label propagation* for small data and using pre-trained for big-data since we need a big enough training-set. please comment that using your approach that considers 3 classes `(App1, App2, App3)`
or 4 classes `(App1, App2, App3)` + `None`? In my scenario, missing `Label\Targets` are labeled  by the string `None`, which is 80% percentage of the data, and the rest labeled `(App1, App2, App3)`